# "Entity Framework" EDMX Diagram Symbols

Tags: entity-framework-6

Does anybody know what the symbols mean that are next to the properties in the Entity Framework:
[image]

Comment: `TypeID` is a primary key. `DateCreated` is just a property. But I wonder what's going on in the `Attribute` table.

Comment: I agree with you about the Attribute table.  In the Attribute table, there is only one primary key (Id).  So, I understand now the symbol.  However, what do the symbols mean for MKT_CODE and AD_Domain?  Those are not keys but attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The first one next to `TypeID` is an indication of a key column. The second one is a symbol for regular property.